# How to copy bulk of data to a given range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello so I am trying to get values from the 'book' sheet then copy it to 'Completed' sheet. It doesnt give any error but doesnt do the copying too. It takes the values form book stores it in the data array but doesnt copy them to the 'Completed' sheet. So I guess there is a problem with the last row.

```
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Book'); //source sheet
  var Datarange = sheet.getRange('Q:Q'); //range to check
  var Datavalue = (Datarange.getValues());
  var dest = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Completed'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
  for (i=0; i<Datavalue.length;i++) {
    if ( Datavalue[i] == "Completed") {
      data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,24).getValues());
      j.push(i);
    }
  }
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); /// copy data to range
```

Comment: Would you please explain the entire scenario, what you are trying to achieve and share a copy of your spreadsheet. It's not reasonable that users should have to read your code in order to try and understand the scenario. You also said _"works fine until the copying row"_ - would you please expand on this; are you getting an error, is the code not working as you expect - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Datavalue is a 2D array so i would suggest that it's not working fine.  And data needs to be 2d array as well.  You need to reread the documentation and correct your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function whoknowswhat() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Book');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,17,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var v=rg.getValues();
  var dest=ss.getSheetByName('Completed');
  var data=[];
  for (i=0; i<v.length;i++) {
    if (v[i][?]=="Completed") {//need another parameter for column
      data.push(v[i]);//v[i] is an entire row 
    }
  }
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Still not copying the rows in the data.

Comment: What is not working? What steps have you taken to debug the problem? Are you getting any errors?